# Filter view using taxonomy name in url

Tags: views, 6, taxonomy-terms

I have a view that shows a thumbnail of the node and the teaser of the node for all nodes of a certain content type. What I want to do is to only show nodes tagged with a certain word, using the url

My website taxonomy page has this format /category/tags/beauty

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Add an Argument to your view with Taxonomy: Term ID (with depth). You may want to use %2 for the title (or %3?). At the bottom of the argument config form you'll see "Set the breadcrumb for the term parents."

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by using `Taxonomy: Term ID` as argument and than `Validator: Taxonomy term`, `Argument type: Term name/synonym converted to Tern ID` as following:

1. Create view (as per the requirement) and the the required fields.
2. Set the path of page display: **category/tags/%**. (Remember `%` is at third place, this we will be using in contextual filter).
3. Add the argument: **Taxonomy: Term ID**.
4. Configuring the added argument by adding **Validator options: Taxonomy term**.
5. Select **Argument type: Term name/synonym converted to Tern ID**.
6. Save the view and clear the cache to check the changes.

[image]